How do I schedule a task to run 4 days before the end of every month with Google Cloud Scheduler?
How do I schedule a task to run 4 days before the end of every month with Google Cloud Scheduler?
Regardless of a month having 28, 29, 30, or 31 days.

Cloud scheduler  doesn't support Cron job format L. But you can try the workaround mentioned here.
